# How to delete files based on Last opened date (not on last accessed date)

Tags: powershell

In our organization there is a need to delete the files which are not opened for last 6 months.

while googling, I am getting the powershell scripts only based on 'lastaccessed' date.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime -le $cutOffDate}
```

But, this doesn't suit our requirement, since I opened some of the files but those files also got deleted (only those files which I have modified are skipped from deletion).

What we required is, the PowerShell script should "only" delete the files that weren't even opened for last 6 months. Files that are opened within 6 months should be skipped from deletion (there is no necessity that the file being modified).

Comment: Sorry my ignorance, but how last opened date different from last accessed date? Notice that by default updating last access time is disabled: `fsutil behavior query DisableLastAccess`.

Comment: The requirement is for shared drive. In that, most of the files are read only files. Users mayn't do any modification to those files(they simply open, read it, and close). Those files shouldn't be deleted. But "Opening and reading" a file doesn't change last accessed date. The 'Last accessed date" get changed only if the file is modified.

Comment: I checked it myself just now. When I enable update of last access time: `fsutil behavior set DisableLastAccess 0` and reboot (maybe not even necessary), then last access time of file updated on file close, if the file was actually read, but not just opened and closed. Including files, for which user does not have write access to.

Comment: @user1532888 you are confusing LastModifiedDate with LastAccessedDate, the former is only updated on write while the later, as PetSerAl has already pointed out, is written after the file has been read.